# Showing FragmentA when back button is pressed on FragmentC in a TabLayout

Tags: android, switch-statement, fragment

Imagine Instagram, when the camera button/add photo button is pressed on the `TabLayout`,pressing the back button will take me back to the feed fragment.

I am having problem of returning to the `HomeFragment` from a full screen activity.

What I did: When the camera button on the `tablayout` is pressed, it will prompt an alert dialog to ask user to choose whether from gallery or camera. Both will prompt a full screen activity. And when back button is pressed, it is stuck at the camera button screen, where I am not planning to design.

What I plan on doing: When back button is pressed from the `alert dialog` box or gallery or camera, it will return to the `HomeFragment`. Below is my code:

#### onCreate

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
    new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabSelected(tab);
            switch (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()) {
                case 2:
                    //do what you want when tab 2 is selected
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SniffsTabActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Choose Food");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Gallery",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SniffsTabActivity.this, MediaActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Camera",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SniffsTabActivity.this, MediaActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            // When back button pressed perform something 
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
});
```

#### showing of fragments:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return HomeFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return SearchFragment.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return ChooseImageFragment.newInstance();
            case 3:
                return FeedActivityFragment.newInstance();
            default:
                return ProfileFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MediaActivity.class override the onBackPressed method or onKeyDown to finish the activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

or

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. But how do I code it to return to HomeFragment when the back button is pressed either from the alert dialog or camera activity. Thanks